# MinGW cross compiling Linux->Windows misses icon in taskbar

Tags: linux, windows, qt, mingw, cross-compiling

I realize this is a very specific question, but maybe someone here has an idea what's happening.

I have a docker image that cross compiles my Qt application with MXE. In my qmake-file I have the line `RC_ICONS = myApp.ico` and the icon gets shown correctly in the explorer. I also have these lines right at the beginning of my main:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setWindowIcon( QIcon("Icon.png") );
```

Still, I only get the blank document icon in my Windows 10 taskbar when I execute the application.

If I compile the Application on Windows (again with MinGW) I do get the icon. So it seems like it's a problem with MinGW on linux, but I have no idea how to proceed with this information.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: while an interesting problem, you're throwing a lot of work onto the reader to test this case. If you can post a super-small set of app code and any required `make` instructions to people can replicate your problem, you might get some help.  Otherwise you'll have to hope that someone else has figured this out already.. (If you make a tiny app, I'd recommend deleting this Q and reposting as a new Q). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Thanks, that's a good point! I'll see if I can throw something together later and post a more detailed question.

Comment: @JayTea Is the .png on the side of the .exe?

Comment: @eyllanesc you mean is it in the same folder as the .exe? Yes, it it.

Comment: okay, why do not you use a qresource?

Comment: @eyllanesc I did, didn't work either. In all cases, compiled on windows with MinGW it does show the icon. Cross-compiled on linux for windows it does not.